# AnyObject is not convertible to String using swift

Tags: ios, string, parse-platform

I am retrieving the current user info from parse and saving it in `data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()` and tring to get the "fullName" of the user to show it in label called `userName` I'm using this :

```
var name:String = self.data["fullName"] as! String // error here: AnyObject is not convertible String.
    self.userName.text = name
```

I saw many question in here but they dint help me. Gave the same error.
`println(self.data)` gave me this :

```
(
"<PFUser: 0x7fa01bd7eed0, objectId: SiA72FwNi2, localId: (null)> {\n    email = \"jhsbdfjhs@jhbs.com\";\n    fullName = \"Khjdf Ujhdsf\";\n    gender = male;\n    profilePicture = \"<PFFile: 0x7fa01bd719b0>\";\n    username = jhsfgj;\n}"
)
```

this is my function:

```
func loadData() {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()!.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {

                var u = user as! PFUser


                self.data.addObject(u)


            }
        })

        println(self.data)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `self.data` is `NSMutableArray` and you can not access `fullName` like this, first you need to get `PFObject` from self.data by giving index like this `self.data[0]` and then get fullName

```
var object:PFObject = self.data[0]
var st:String = object["fullName"] as! String
```